# how to show dev boxes on condition of url id and hide others vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

5 links on the left side  and box on the right i wanna to change content of this box using the links on the left
let me explain more[my Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi1BS.png)

i wanna when i click on any link on the side bar the content of the box change, i tried do this whith loop 5 boxes for the 5 links but how i will show one box and hide others using the id param in the url?

```html
<div class="body col-md">
  <b-row>
    <b-col md="12">
      <b-form-textarea v-model="qs.text" size="sm" id="textarea-auto-height" placeholder="Question" rows="2" max-rows="2"></b-form-textarea>
    </b-col>
    <b-col md="6">
      <label>A</label>
      <b-form-input v-model="qs.chooseA" placeholder="Enter choose 1"></b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col md="6">
      <label>B</label>
      <b-form-input v-model="qs.chooseB" placeholder="Enter choose 2"></b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col md="6">
      <label>C</label>
      <b-form-input v-model="qs.chooseC" placeholder="Enter choose 3"></b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col md="6">
      <label>D</label>
      <b-form-input v-model="qs.chooseD" placeholder="Enter choose 4"></b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col md="6">
      <b-form-file class="file" placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..." drop-placeholder="Drop file here..." ></b-form-file>
    </b-col>
```

this my box code

Answer (score 0):

I think you left out your sidebar code, but if I understood you correctly you want to change the data in the form when you click on a question in the sidebar.

You can do this with the @click event on the sidebar buttons, add a function which changes the data in the qs object when a button is clicked:

```
<b-sidebar>
  ...
  <b-buttom v-for="question in questions" :key="question.id" @click="updateQuestionObject(question)"> {{ question.text }}</b-button>
  ...
</b-sidebar>

...

<script>
...
  methods: {
    updateQuestionObject(question) {
      qs = question
    }
  }
</script>
```

This would also make your UI code dynamic so you dont have to hardcode the number of questions.

The "key" attribute doesnt need to be the question id (I dont know what your question objects look like so I just used that) it just has to be a unique identifier.